# imagettftext issue with Drawing within the image border / size

Tags: php, fonts, truetype, imagettftext

I have a script that dynamically draws a preview images for fonts (TTF).
Since each font is designed differently some of them doesn’t fit on the drawing area, and some gets very small.

What would be the best dynamic approach to solve a problem like that? To dynamically adjust the text size to always draw at a readable size within the defined image border?

Here is my code,

```php
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(600, 70);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 600, 70, $white);
    $text = 'Testing...';
    // The file name is hard coded in this example.
    $font = 'arial.ttf';
    imagettftext($im, 50, 0, 10, 60, $black, $font, $text);
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: "The best way" is purely a matter of opinion here - to be specific, *your own opinion*. What would look best, for your purposes? Only you can decide.

Comment: Well, the best way would be to pass the text size as a parameter to the script, but since the script is automated to handle thousands of fonts. Managing and inputting the text size is not manageable manually. And I am stuck here.